# Retrieve row number by a button's click event in DataGrid

Tags: c#, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

I am adding a label and two buttons to the first column of a `DataGrid`:

```
//buttons
DataGridTemplateColumn dgc = new DataGridTemplateColumn();
DataTemplate dtm = new DataTemplate();

FrameworkElementFactory label = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
label.SetValue(Label.ContentProperty, new Binding("Name"));

FrameworkElementFactory button = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
button.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, "7");
button.SetValue(Button.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Webdings"));
button.SetValue(Button.HeightProperty, 18.0);
button.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(previous_event));

FrameworkElementFactory button2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Button));
button2.SetValue(Button.ContentProperty, "8");
button2.SetValue(Button.FontFamilyProperty, new FontFamily("Webdings"));
button2.SetValue(Button.HeightProperty, 18.0);
button2.AddHandler(Button.ClickEvent, new RoutedEventHandler(next_event));

FrameworkElementFactory label2 = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(Label));
label2.SetValue(Label.ContentProperty, "");

FrameworkElementFactory btnReset = new FrameworkElementFactory(typeof(DockPanel));
btnReset.AppendChild(label);
btnReset.AppendChild(button);
btnReset.AppendChild(button2);
btnReset.AppendChild(label2);

btnReset.SetValue(DockPanel.HorizontalAlignmentProperty, HorizontalAlignment.Right);
btnReset.SetValue(DockPanel.HeightProperty, 24.0);

//set the visual tree of the data template  
dtm.VisualTree = btnReset;
dgc.Header = "Events / Time";
dgc.CellTemplate = dtm;
dgc.Width = 300;

dgTimeline.Columns.Add(dgc);
```

How do I get the row number in which the clicked button is? In the `previous_event` and `next_event` methods I have tried:

```
public void previous_event(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("prev " + ((DockPanel)((Button)e.OriginalSource).Parent).Parent.GetType());
}
```

Trying to get `DockPanel`'s parent triggers a `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a `Button` inside a `DataGrid`, the row with the clicked button will automatically be selected. So you can just grab the `SelectedIndex` of the DataGrid.